# Is it possible to import a DB from a .sql file in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

The application that I am creating will have a database that will have questions and answers. My problem is that I will be required to make hundreds of inserts to make the database complete.  What is the best way to make it possible to do hundreds of insert statements.  I am also thinking about to creating the database through the SQlite manager and from it to export a .sql file and use it to create a DB for my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you have static data inside your database the it would be better to create the database from SQLite Manager and keep it inside assets folder and then copy it from assets folder into your databases directory when your Application starts. Also check the database file if exists the don't copy else it will overwrite the previous file everytime when you start Application.

Comment: thanks for the response, i didnt had much of a success with that. isnt there a bettter way to do it.

Comment: `i didnt had much of a success with that`, what problem you have in that?

Comment: i have seen few tutorials on using own database, as what i have seen is they copy the database. same way can we copy the data froma .sql file to a string resource so we can use it with execsql.